VS Code Debug Console (JS) - Custom logger function outputs the same file and line number every time, how can I provide path/line of caller?
All my console.log calls are wrapped with a function in a file called Logger.js.
Whenever I log to the console using this wrapper function, I lose the ability to easily see where the log came from (file:line #), instead it just tells me that each call came from Logger.js:101:

Is there a way to show the path to the caller of my Logger function instead?

This question is similar to: Extending console.log without affecting log line, A proper wrapper for console.log with correct line number?, Wrapping console.log with additional function and correct line numbers, and many others. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. In particular, what you want your wrapper to do?
